# Как проверить количество блоков div в блоке div ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я использую библиотеку jQuery Masonry для галлереи. Однако, там идет центрирование первого елемента `top:0; left:0;` Если его поставить по центру, то все остальные фото пойдут так же.
Как написать проверку на js / jQuery, если div 1 ( один ), то использовать для него стили которые выровнят его по центру?

```
<div style="position:relative; min-width:80%; clear:both; height:auto; margin:0 auto; padding-top:2%;padding-bottom:16%;">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
          <div class="grid-item marg_center">
            <a class="example-image-link" href="http://timworld.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bauhaus_in_Tel_Aviv_7_120x80.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" >
            <img class="example-image" src="http://timworld.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bauhaus_in_Tel_Aviv_7_120x80.jpg"  alt=""/>
</a>
                </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if ($('div.grid').length == 1) { сделать что то } `? :)

Comment: спасибище, я думал как сформировать условие, помогло.if ($('div.grid-item').length == 1) {
$('.grid').css({'margin':'0 auto','width':'20%'});
$('.grid-item ').css('width','100%');
}

Answer (score 1):

Попобуйте использовать функцию `element.childNodes.length`. Если возвращает 0, значит в блоке нету блоков, а затем уже применяете нужные стили.